# Download and execute binary in go

Tags: go

I'm trying to download a file and execute it in my windows laptop.
My program is well downloaded but when i try to execute it in my code i get this windows error : Your file cannot be executed because the process is busy.

Here is my code :

```
fmt.Println(stdout)
out, err := os.Create("output.exe")
defer out.Close()
resp, err := http.Get("http://IP:8000/myfile.exe")
defer resp.Body.Close()
n, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

c := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "start", "C:\\PATH\\output.exe")
if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
}
```

I'm pretty new with go.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like `out` is till open when `exec.Command` is run. `defer` will only close it at the end of the lexical scope. Try to `Close` it after the `Sleep`

Comment: I still get the error, but thanks for the fast reply

Comment: Why do you use `cmd /C` instead of using `exec.Command` directly? Why is the program you're executing in `PATH`, is your Go script in PATH? Did you try to run it manually after downloading? Did you try to split apart the download code from the `exec` code and see which one is bad? In short *this is not a Go question, it's just a general Windows question*

Comment: When i try to run it directly with exec.Command i get don't get any output, it seems to works great with cmd manually that's why. I compile it with linux for a Windows system, I don't the issue come from my PATH here. Everything work when i split the files, and it work manually also. I was thinking it's about out.close also. But now I have no clues.

Comment: Moreover i want to launch my program in another process, because I'm not advanced with go i was thinking cmd will do it for me.

Comment: You’re not going to get any output unless you try to get the output. Maybe start with `CombinedOutput`

Answer (score 0):

for anyone still having the same problem, you need to return to defer to take place:

```
func download(){
   fmt.Println(stdout)
   out, err := os.Create("output.exe")
   defer out.Close()
   resp, err := http.Get("http://IP:8000/myfile.exe")
   defer resp.Body.Close()
   n, err := io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
   return
}

func execute(){
   c := exec.Command("C:\\PATH\\output.exe")
   if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
   }
   return
}

func main(){
   download()
   execute()
}
```